# Call REST API with Basic AUTH without dialog to enter username and password

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, basic-authentication

I need to access external API and display a website page, without any authentication dialog box. But i am not able to bypass the dialog box to enter username and password.

I tried different ajax combinations but not working, and when I use dataType as **JSONP** it always asks to enter a dialog box asking me to enter username and password.
Otherwise get the error message: "blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status".

Code:

```
$.ajax({
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       type: "GET", 
       data: '',                    
       url: 'https://www.XXTEST.com?from=2022-10-30',
       headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
       },
       beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa("username" + ":" + "password")); 
       },
       success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
       }
});
```

Comment: if you try using curl from the command line with the same parameters, does that work?

Comment: I have not tried with curl, it's working fine with the postman.